# Share Excel "Template Formulas" between sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that takes user inputted values and performs some fixed computations to generate a number of cells.  I plan to use these computations in a number of sheets with different user inputted values.

The idea is that a sheet can be duplicated at will and the users simply change/fill out certain values and get useful information generated in all the other cells.

How can I share the template formulas between the sheets such that, for maintainability purposes, any changes could be easily propagated to all sheets?

Would VBA macros be required? (some already exist for more complex computations, but for the most parts, computations simply use values of cells in the spreadsheet and can be expressed as an inline formula)

Example:

Sheet 1:

```
User value    | 12345
Computation 1 | 29239
Computation 2 | 3103
Computation 3 | 3941
```

Sheet 2:

```
User value    | 12346
Computation 1 | 23091
Computation 2 | 3092
Computation 3 | 3111
```

where Computations 1, 2, and 3 are functions of `User Value`.

The idea is that if, for example, I decide to change how computation 2 is done I can do it once in a centralized place instead of once per sheet.

Comment: Related question: Is it possible to share cells between sheets?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to do it directly without VBA. But if you select all sheets that need to be changed then changing it on one sheet will propagate the change to all sheets. (I don't select multiple sheets very often, but it's either Ctrl+click or Shift+click on the tabs. I *think* Ctrl+click selects individual sheets and Shift+click selects all sheets from the selected sheet to the one clicked on.)

Another option that uses just a little VBA is to write a custom function. A VBA function can be used as a function in a cell. If you write a custom function that does what you want (saved either in a module or in the workbook's own class), you can just change that instead of changing the worksheets themselves.